# Apex Test Class

Tags: testing, controller, apex, autosave

newbie here...thanks for your patience.  I'm interested in writing a test class for the following controller, but not sure where to begin:

```
public class savecontroller
{
    private final Emp__c emps;
    public savecontroller(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
    {
        this.emps= (Emp__c)controller.getRecord();
    }
    public void autosave()
    {
        upsert emps;
    }   
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a little bit strange... From this part:

```
public savecontroller(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
```

it looks like your controller is not really a "controller", but more like an extension of a standard controller for Emp__c object. I know, it doesn't affect anythingin your post (except maybe semantics), **BUT (!)** it does have an affect on how you write your test class. Since this is an extension, test class would look something like this:

```
@isTest
public class saveconttroller_test {

    public static Emp__c test_emp; // declaration

    static {
        test_emp = new Emp__c(); 
        insert test_emp; //since you have upsert you can leave this out
    }

    static testMethod void testsavecotroller() {

        Test.startTest();
        //in the next two lines we contruct standard controller and the extension
        ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.StandardController(test_emp);
        savecontroller ext = new savecontroller(sc);
        ext.autosave();
        Test.stopTest(); 
    } 
}
```

Now, let me point out a few things... first, as I'm sure you know, test should cover as much code as possible. SF requires 75%, but the closer you get to 100% the better. But **(!)**, you should always include something to assert if your method is doing what it is suppose to be doing. For example in your case, i would change method autosave() like this:

```
 public PageReference autosave()
    {
        try {
             upsert emps;
             return new ApexPages.StandardController(test_emp).view();

        } catch(Exception e) {
             return null;        
        }
    }
```

By doing so, you can include `System.assertEquals(ref1, ref2);` in your test class, wher ref1 is reference you would expect (if the upsertion was successful this would be test_emp page reference) and ref2 would be the reference you actually get from the test.
Second thing is using `static` method in the test. Whatever you write in this method will always execute on `Test.startTest();` call.

Hope this helps you! :)
Cheers, G.